# Android: Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int

Tags: java, android, string

If I try

```
nltxt = nllen.toString();
```

with `nllen` being

```
int nllen = nl.getLength();
```

I get the error

> Cannot invoke `toString()` on the primitive type int.

I want to convert the int to string so i can display the number of entries with Log...
Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 29):

Primitives do not have any fields or methods. Sometimes the compiler will "autobox" your primitive into the corresponding class, `Integer` in this case. Perhaps that is what you expected in this case. Sometimes the compiler will not do this. In this case it does not automatically autobox it.

You have a few alternatives:

1. `String.valueOf(nltxt)`
2. `"" + nltxt` (or if you have something useful to write along with the number, do `"nltxt equals " + nltxt`
3. Do the "autoboxing" manually: `new Integer(nltxt).toString()`.
4. Format it in some custom way: `String.format("nltxt is %d which is bad%n", nltxt)`

Comment: I could agree on that 3 is a bit convoluted. But why not 2?

Comment: aioobe: Its not very readable.  If someone is quickly scanning through the code they might miss that you were just trying to convert it to a strong.

Answer (score 12):

Primitive types aren't objects and as such don't have any methods.

To convert it to a String use `String.valueOf(nlTxt)`.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `Integer.toString(nllen);` for this.