# String.valueOf(int value) gives error

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an `int` into a `String` so that I can put the `String` values into an SQLite Cursor. I've tried multiple syntax and methods but none seem to work for me.

The Error occurs in `MangaItemDB()` while trying to convert any `Int` types aswell as the `boolean`.

I've looked through several articles [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028974/android-cannot-invoke-tostring-on-the-primitive-type-int) but none works for me.

Here's my code:

```
public class MangaItem {

private int _id;
private String mangaName;
private String mangaLink;
private static String mangaAlpha;
private static int mangaCount;
private static int alphaCount;

private boolean mangaComplete = false;



public MangaItem MangaItemDB(int id, String mangaName, String mangaLink, String mangaAlpha, String mangaCount, String alphaCount, String mangaComplete) {
    MangaItem MangaItemDB = new MangaItem();
    MangaItemDB._id = id;
    MangaItemDB.mangaName = mangaName;
    MangaItemDB.mangaLink = mangaLink;
    MangaItemDB.mangaAlpha = mangaAlpha;
    MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(int mangaCount);
    MangaItemDB.alphaCount = Integer.toString(getAlphaCount());
    MangaItemDB.mangaComplete = String.valueOf(getMangaComplete());
    return MangaItemDB;


}

public void incrementMangaCount() {
    mangaCount++;
}

public int getMangaCount() {
    return mangaCount;
}

public void incrementAlphaCount() {
    alphaCount++;
}

public int getAlphaCount() {
    return alphaCount;
}

public boolean setMangaComplete(boolean mangaComplete) {
    return true;
}

public boolean getMangaComplete() {
    return mangaComplete;
}

/**
 * @return the mangaName
 */
public String getMangaName() {
    return mangaName;
}

/**
 * @param mangaName the mangaName to set
 */
public void setMangaName(String mangaName) {
    this.mangaName = mangaName;
}

/**
 * @return the mangaLink
 */
public String getMangaLink() {
    return mangaLink;
}

/**
 * @param mangaLink the mangaLink to set
 */
public void setMangaLink(String mangaLink) {
    this.mangaLink = mangaLink;
}

/**
 * @return the mangaAlpha
 */
public String getMangaAlpha() {
    return mangaAlpha;
}

/**
 * @param mangaAlpha the mangaAlpha to set
 */
public void setMangaAlpha(String mangaAlpha) {
    this.mangaAlpha = mangaAlpha;
}

/**
 * @return the _id
 */
public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

/**
 * @param _id the _id to set
 */
public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

}
```

The lines :

```
    MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(mangaCount);
    MangaItemDB.alphaCount = Integer.toString(getAlphaCount());
    MangaItemDB.mangaComplete = String.valueOf(getMangaComplete());
```

all give "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Int"

Comment: Make sure that the type of `MangaItemDB.mangaCount` is indeed String etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(int mangaCount);
```

That code shouldn't even compile. You shouldn't pass the parameter type when calling a method, but instead when you call a method you simply pass in the parameter:

```
MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(mangaCount);
```

Please post **all** compilation errors if you have them so we don't have to guess at them.

**Edit**
You state:

```
MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(mangaCount);
MangaItemDB.alphaCount = Integer.toString(getAlphaCount());
MangaItemDB.mangaComplete = String.valueOf(getMangaComplete());
```

> all give "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Int"

This suggests that you're trying to assign Strings to int variables, and so there appears to be no need to convert the results to a String. Why not simply assign ints to ints and booleans to booleans?

```
MangaItemDB.mangaCount = mangaCount;
MangaItemDB.alphaCount = getAlphaCount();
MangaItemDB.mangaComplete = getMangaComplete();
```

Also, why are you using static variables? What is the justification for doing this? There are very specific times when you will want to use static variables, but most often your variables should be instance variables.

Comment: `MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(mangaCount);` doesnt work for me. I've tried many variations The ones posted are only the current ones

Comment: @Davidrd91: "doesn't work for me" doesn't tell us enough information to be able to help you. How doesn't it work? Do you get a compilation error? A run-time exception? Misbehavior? These details will matter, so please let us know.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Question has been edited.

Comment: @David: again, see edit to my answer.

Comment: The variables `mangaCount` and `alphaCount` are counters of elements in an XML and as such are type `Int`. I understand now as to why the `Int` values would not convert, as I was saving them in type `Int` variables.

Comment: @David: that doesn't explain why the variables are static. I would suspect that they shouldn't be static.

Comment: as for being static `mangaCount` really has no reason to be now that I think about it but `mangaAlpha` is the count of a sorting element. I will use it as a sort of ID#. For example all `MangaItem` with `alphaCount` value of 0 will begin with the letter A. As such I would have the `alphaCount` not change until another category element is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

```
MangaItem mangaItemDB = new MangaItem();
MangaItemDB._id = id;
MangaItemDB.mangaName = mangaName;
MangaItemDB.mangaLink = mangaLink;
MangaItemDB.mangaAlpha = mangaAlpha;
MangaItemDB.mangaCount = String.valueOf(int mangaCount);  //change to mangaItemDB .setMangaCount(String.valueOf(mangaCount));
MangaItemDB.alphaCount = Integer.toString(getAlphaCount());
MangaItemDB.mangaComplete = String.valueOf(getMangaComplete());
```

See above code, Very bad practice. You should use getter and setter methods like :

```
mangaItemDB.setMangaCount(String.valueOf(mangaCount));
```

Comment: just tried `mangaItemDB.setMangaCount(String.valueOf(mangaCount));` but this returns error: "setMangaCount(String) is undefined" I suppose I could add this method if no other solution is found.

Comment: not only that, above all fields, make them private, provide getter and setter methods. Don't make fields static unless it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Because MangaCount and Alpha count are static, you do not want to be setting them in the non static context - essentially you are doing nothing. If you want the MangaItem to hold those values, than make a non-static version of MangaCount and AlphaCount.

MangaComplete() returns a boolean, so you aren't going to need to parse it.

Static are variables and methods you want only one kind of for the class, and non-static variables and methods are class specific - they only can be used from the object itself. It seems like set and get MangaCount+AlphaCount should be static.