# how to return null to int method

Tags: java

iam new to programming.iam wrking on a quiz game software. here i want a count down to be printed as "3,2,1,go...go...go"

```
  package t2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Stopwatch {
static int interval;
static Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = 3;
    System.out.println("3");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());

        }
    }, delay, period);
}



 private static final int setInterval() {
    String go="go...go...go";
    if (interval == 2)
    {

        timer.cancel();
        return go;
    }

      return --interval;

}
}
```

this says that setInterval() has int as return value.if i place `System.out.print("go");`
in the place of `return go;` it prints go and prints 1 which is out of requirement. please any buddy can tell me how to do this.

Comment: Why not move the contents of the interval method to `run`.  This way you don't care about the return statement...

Comment: Your method is defined to return an int -- therefore, you can't return a string.

Comment: Why not check if the return value is 0, and if it's 0, print out "go...go...go" instead of the number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the return type of `setInterval` to object to take advantage of the overloaded `println` method and the conditional should check for 1 instead of 2.  Also use `print` instead of `println` to have the output on the same line.

```
private static final Object setInterval() {
    String go="go...go...go";
    if (interval == 1)
    {

        timer.cancel();
        return go;
    }
    return --interval;
}
```

**Full Example**

```
 package t2;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class Stopwatch {
        static int interval;
        static Timer timer;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int delay = 1000;
            int period = 1000;
            timer = new Timer();
            interval = 3;
            System.out.print("3,");
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                public void run() {
                    System.out.print(setInterval() + ",");

                }
            }, delay, period);
        }

        private static final Object setInterval() {
            String go = "go...go...go";
            if (interval == 1) {

                timer.cancel();
                return go;
            }

            return --interval;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to change your setInterval() method to return a string like such:

```
private static final String setInterval() {
    String go="go...go...go";
    if (interval == 2)
    {

        timer.cancel();
        return go;
    }

    --interval;
    return String.valueOf(interval);
}
```

Comment: this shows error as "The primitive type int of interval does not have a field toString" and thanks for reply do reply on this problem

Comment: @3bu1 -- See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028991/1073631 (also, I edited above)

Comment: In my opinion, this is the better answer, it is strongly typed and clear what the method is used for.