# Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int

Tags: java, android

this is my code to set a value to a TextView

```
enter code here

public void addHours(View view){
    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newHours_Value);
    String hourValue = R.id.enterHours.getText().toint();
    mTextView.setText("hourValue");
}
```

but the R.id.enterHours.GetText() comes up with an error

Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int

what am i doing wrong please.

Comment: You are invoking getText() on the primitive type int. Possibly call it on `mTextView`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953077/android-what-is-r-why-is-it-so-cryptic

Comment: See this post [Android: Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028974/android-cannot-invoke-tostring-on-the-primitive-type-int

Answer (score 4):

This

```
 R.id.enterHours
```

returns an `int`. That's why when you initialize a `View` you do it like

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newHours_Value);
```

The `(TextView)` casts it to a `TextView` so you can call its methods on it like `getText().toString()`. So what you probably want is

```
TextView hourValueTV = (TextView) findViewById*R.id.enterHours);  //assuming its a TextView and not EditText
String hourValue = hourValueTV.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what codeMagic said:

In this case, you should set text with the variable name (reference) of the String and not value ("hourValue", unless you want your text to be hourValue).

It should be

```
  mTextView.setText(hourValue);
```

Comment: Many thanks all, i did note the other questions but could not understand the answers, i am a newbee to android programming